# Boost returning values from multithread vector

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I am trying to develop a code which generates N threads into a loop. Each thread generates 40 random numbers and pick from them the highest. Afterwards, I have to choose the highest number from all. However, when I return the highest value of each thread (b) it is empty, this is the code I am using:

```
class rdm_thr
{
public:
rdm_thr()
{
}
void rdmgen()
{
    default_random_engine generator;
    double rdm;
    b=0;
    normal_distribution<double> normal(0, 1);
    for(int i=0; i<40; i++)
    {
        rdm = normal(generator);
        if(rdm>b)
            b = rdm;
    }
}
};


void main()
{
vector<boost::thread *> z;
vector<rdm_thr> o;
boost::function<void()> th_func;

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    o.push_back(rdm_thr());

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    th_func = boost::bind(&rdm_thr::rdmgen, &o[i]);
    boost::thread thr(th_func);
    z.push_back(&thr);
}

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    z[i]->join();
}
}
```

Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change your class logic as such:

```
class rdm_thr
{
    public:
        rdm_thr() {}

        void rdmgen()
        {
            ...
        }

        void join() { t.join(); }

        void start()
        {
            t = boost::thread(boost::bind(&rdm_thr::rdmgen, this));
        }


    private:
        boost::thread t;
        // could also be pointer type and 'new/delete' would have to be used in that event
};

#define TSZ 2

void main()
{
    std::vector<rdm_thr*> o;
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < TSZ; i++) {
        o.push_back(new rdm_thr());
        o.back()->start();
    }
    for (i = 0; i < TSZ; i++) {
        o[i]->join();
        delete o[i]; //clean up
    }
}
```

And if you didn't want to change your class logic, you could do the following in your main function:

```
#define TSZ 2
void main()
{
    std::vector<boost::thread *> z;
    std::vector<rdm_thr *> o;
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < TSZ; i++) {
        o.push_back(new rdm_thr());
        z.push_back(new boost::thread(boost::bind(&rdm_thr::rdmgen, o.back())));
    }
    for (i = 0; i < TSZ; i++) {
        z[i]->join();
        delete z[i];
        delete o[i];
    }
}
```

I don't have access to a compiler right now so I can't verify 100%, but as your asking more on theory, the above code is to help illustrate alternative ways of achieving similar results.

I hope that can help

Comment: Although that was not idea of the code, it helped me to solve it, thank you very much!

Comment: Glad I could help even though I misunderstood :) I can also edit for more clarity if needed